# mod rewrite rule for multiple files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using two php files in my CMS system. The first one takes the request http://mydomain.com/page.php?page=about-us and the second one http://mydomain.com/otherpage.php?page=additional-page.

I would like to put into my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)$ page.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)$ otherpage.php?page=$1
```

and have both rules working. Could you help?

Comment: So there's absolutely no difference between what would go to `page.php` vs `otherpage.php`? Does one contain numbers? Does one contain periods or dashes? Is one always 2 words? If there's no difference, then you can't have both rules.

Comment: Can you describe more clearly what you mean?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt replies. My idea is that I have two tables - pages and otherpages. I am OK to have page.php?table=pages$id=5 or page.php?table=otherpages&id=9 but it will be translated to http://website.com/pages/page-title and http://website.com/otherpages/page-title. I need to remove /pages/ and /otherpages/ form the url if I want to use two parameters in the query string